# Is it possible to run parts of a code in python 2.x while the rest is written in python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-2.x

Is it possible to have python 3.x code and to execute 2.x code (e.g. a function call) in it?

```
#Code written in python 3.x
.
.
.
.
.
.


#This is the python 2.x part with Function2x() written in python 2.x
Function2x()
#End of python 2.x part


#Code written in python 3.x
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Would this be considered bad practice? If so, how could one circumvent this problem if porting the code from 3.x to 2.x is not an option?

Comment: it may help you to convert ur script from 2 to 3 https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/2to3.html

Answer (score 2):

In general it is probably not possible. At least there is no easy way.

But there are some workarrounds depending on what problem are you trying to solve. e.g. If you have python3 code that is not compatible with python2 interpreter and you have to run it in python2, you may try to use [future](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/future) module.

If you have python2 code to convert to python3 then you can use [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/2to3.html) utility mentioned by @smart-manoj.

Also if you only have some simple python3 methods to run and return single result you may consider calling external python3 process from python2 using [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) method. This could of course be also used the other way round i.e. calling python2 interpreter from python3. But you will quickly have some issues with that solution, so I would not recommend this.